# How to handle cross-language questions correctly

Tags: discussion, languages

There is [an existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317069/collect-all-minimum-solutions-from-a-backtrackable-predicate/27470503#27470503) on a specific programming language, and I would like to know, how this very problem would be solved in SQL - which so far has not been mentioned in this question at all (except for a comment from me). I first considered to put a bounty out with a statement to that end and maybe adding the SQL tag. But on the other hand I do not want that OP gets downvotes on this.
Making this a new question looks like a duplicate. So what is the right way to get that information?

Answer (score 6):

Solving the same problem in a different language is a different problem, that is entirely worthy of a different question.  The two questions would be related, and mentioning the existing question would be helpful in both determining the level of the question and as a resource to aid answerers.

Placing a bounty that essentially is asking for answers to a noticeably different question wouldn't be appropriate.  Answers posted for the sake of the bounty should still be answering the original question the bounty is posted to.  The new answers might go into more detail, cover additional cases, etc., but someone who didn't know of the bounty that looks at the answer still ought to think that the post answers the original question.